# How to combine two images

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have a single image. And I have a collection view with banner images. Now,I need to combine these 2 images into single image without affecting their quality and height so that I could be able to download the merged image. I searched but couldn't find proper solutions for swift 3. My code is given as:

Comment: Please describe what exactly you are trying to approach "combining". Also, please let us know what you have tried already and what the actual problem is you are running into.

Comment: It means that I need to add 2 images height wise. I have mentioned profileImg of height 200 and bannerImage of height 60, now I need to add these two images into single image of height 260. Did you understand it now ?? Plzz help me out I am beginner in swift. @shallowThought

Comment: I assume you have chosen the title "combining two images in swift 3" because "combining two images" already exists. Please do [a simple reasearch](https://www.google.es/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&q=swift+combining+two+images&oq=swift+combining+two+images&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4265.5734.0.6636.6.6.0.0.0.0.205.705.3j2j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.310...0i7i30i19k1j0i19k1.0.q_t4EDTSw3Q), try to solve the puzzle yourself and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46255728/edit) your question with a) relevant code of what you have tried and b) a description what goes wrong.

Comment: No , I couldn't get proper solutions in swift 3. I got some swift solutions but the terms are deprecated in swift 3. So plzz help me out to solve it in swift 3 ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per as your question You have to add two images and show up in a single  UIImageView.

Here is a simple example of adding two images vertically and showing up in an UIImageView -

```
    let topImage = UIImage(named: "image1.png") // 355 X 200
    let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "image2.png")  // 355 X 60

    let size = CGSize(width: (topImage?.size.width)!, height: (topImage?.size.height)! + (bottomImage?.size.height)!)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)

    topImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height: (topImage?.size.height)!))
    bottomImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:(topImage?.size.height)!, width: size.width,  height: (bottomImage?.size.height)!))

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // I've added an UIImageView, You can change as per your requirement.
    let mergeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 200, width: 355, height: 260))

    // Here is your final combined images into a single image view.
    mergeImageView.image = newImage
```

I hope it will help you to start with.

Comment: It get merged but the height of bottomImage gets squeezed and gets small. The image comes distorted. I dont want bottomImage to get compressed. Any idea ? @ Amir Khan

Comment: It will gets squeezed and gets small because it's resolution is different from the top one.
so you have to make the exact size of  the bottom image which is larger in width and smaller in height as you need.